# Suicide and social networks

Tags: psychology

*Social media platforms provide potential opportunities for individuals to connect to support or treatment they need. For instance, social media posts that convey messages of despair or a pattern of increasing hopelessness over a period of time could spur outreach from peers, who in turn can help connect a friend or teammate to commanders and professionals*.
http://www.dodlive.mil/index.php/2017/01/social-media-offers-tools-to-improve-mental-health-reduce-suicide/

But what they're most worried about is social media causing depression to develop, or exacerbating a person's mental state, worsening it every time they log back in. According to the Anxiety and Depression Association of America, depression isn't characterized by fleeting feelings of anxiety or sadness.
http://www.forbes.com/sites/amitchowdhry/2016/04/30/study-links-heavy-facebook-and-social-media-usage-to-depression/#7c5bca4a7e4b

A *recent study found that people who use anywhere from seven to 10 social-media platforms are three times more likely to be depressed or anxious, compared to those using no more than two*
http://nypost.com/2016/12/22/your-social-media-addiction-is-giving-you-depression/

Do social groups really increase the risk of depression?

Comment: The dodlive link appears the suggest that social media can help depressed people and the WSJ article is behind a pay wall, does that article make the claim that social groups increase risk of depression?

Comment: You are presenting two arguments (pro and con) of a large discussion. That is not what this website is for, it's for proving/disproving [notable claims](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2506/what-is-a-notable-claim). Can you [edit] your question that way?

Comment: I changed the wsj link to a non pay one that concludes that use social media very frequently have 2.7 times the likelihood of depression

Comment: Note that the Pittsburgh study (Primack et al) only found an **association** between social media and depression.  It does not claim to have shown **causation**.  The Post's headline "Your social media addiction is giving you depression" does suggest causation but that is not supported by the study.

Comment: Is why I post it here, I have a friend with disabilities who runs an online social network that acts as a virtual community. Her members lives seem enriched by multiple social media outlets, not diminished. I would love other supporting studies of how online groups are either neutral or positive on mental health issues and mood

Comment: I think this is related to this: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/20373/are-discussions-about-suicide-themselves-suicide-triggers?rq=1 quite a bit, might want to take a look at that.

Comment: As a nurse I can state we encourage discussions on mood, especially suicidal ideation. My concern is trollers or abusive moderators. Although i don't think social networks themselves can produce more than irritation in those with healthy psyches, i can see how those with minimal real life interaction or esteem issues could be hurt by rejection or harassment